# Upgrading RAM, iMac 27'' 2019: Is it better to mix Apple/Crucial modules, or substitute all old modules with new ones?

Tags: imac, hardware, upgrade, memory

In an ideal situation, if money is not an issue, what is a better option?
I have an iMac 27" 2019, with 2x16 GB RAM original modules from Apple (2 slots occupied, 2 slots empty). Using the "System scan results" on the Crucial website, the suggested setup is to buy 2 x 16GB DDR4 modules to install into the 2 empty slots. Another option that I have in mind is to remove the original 2 modules, and install 4 x 16GB new modules from Crucial.

In terms of performance, and if money is not an issue, is it better to

1. add 2x16GB modules from Crucial (having 2 slots of Apple RAM, and 2 slots of Crucial) with the advantage of using the original Apple modules, or
2. remove the Apple modules, and install 4x16GB modules from Crucial, with the advantage of not having to mix modules of different kind/vendor?

Rephrasing: is it better to 1) mix Apple and Crucial modules or 2) having all Crucial modules?
Is there a difference in quality between Apple and Crucial modules? Are there any loss of performance when you mix them?

Sources:

https://www.crucial.com/

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201191#27inch2019

EDIT:
On the apple website, it seems that it is better to not mix apple and third party modules. It is written that ".on the Apple website (the link in my question) it is written that

"For optimal memory performance, DIMMs should be the same capacity, speed, and vendor."

Answer (score 1):

As long as all the modules are of the same specification, then there should be no problem, as that's exactly what the spec is there to ensure.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought but...on the Apple website (the link in my question) it is written that "For optimal memory performance, DIMMs should be the same capacity, speed, and vendor. "